Specifying an advanced GARCH model in R
I am trying to implement a specific kind of GARCH model in R.
The simple description of the model is the following:
I am trying to build an GARCH(1,1) model, where I_t is a dummy variable indicating an announcement day. S_t is a continuous variable indicating a surprise component. The idea is to allow the S_t to affect the conditional mean and the variance. s_t is defined as:
1+(sum from k-1 to 1)gamma(k)I(k)S_t(k)
So eventually the idea is to capture the anticipation of the event, the contemporaneous effect of the event, and persistence effect of the event on variance. The model is developed by Brenner, Pasquariello, and Subrahmanyam (2009).

I have currently used the rugarch package with the following specification:
spec <- ugarchspec(
  variance.model = list(model = "sGARCH", garchOrder = c(1, 1), external.regressors = variance_regressors_matrix),
  mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(1, 0), include.mean = TRUE, external.regressors = mean_regressors_matrix),
  distribution.model = "norm"
)

mean_regressors_matrix is a matrix that contains interaction terms between announcement day dummy (logical vector from (1,0)) and S_t (has a value when dummy = 1, otherwise 0).
variance_regressors_matrix is a matrix that contains interaction terms between the announcement day dummy and abs(S_t), as well as pre-event and post-event dummies (1,0).
The results seem weird since estimates for vxreg 1:3 are all zero and p-value 1. This of course can be true but I am wondering whether the problem lies in my R coding instead and if this code is actually the equivalent of the image equation?
Here are my results:
fit <- ugarchfit(spec, returns_ts)
fit

Robust Standard Errors:
        Estimate  Std. Error  t value Pr(>|t|)
mu      0.050426    0.012767   3.9496 0.000078
ar1     0.021225    0.013780   1.5402 0.123500
mxreg1  0.215722    0.080457   2.6812 0.007335
omega   0.022069    0.005931   3.7211 0.000198
alpha1  0.088271    0.012191   7.2409 0.000000
beta1   0.898635    0.012474  72.0385 0.000000
vxreg1  0.000000    0.072587   0.0000 1.000000
vxreg2  0.000000    0.056018   0.0000 1.000000
vxreg3  0.000000    0.073370   0.0000 1.000000

LogLikelihood : -8045.658 



Great! Have I now done it correctly?

Much better, thanks. We'll have to wait and see if others agree to reopen this. Good luck.
